# Creating a HTML DOM select element in Javascript and having an onchange event

Tags: javascript, html, dom, select, onchange

I am creating HTML DOM elements using Javascript (yes, I know it's nasty).
I can get the select element created but I cannot add an onchange property.

Example:

```
var sel = document.createElement('select');
sel.id = 'someID';
sel.title = 'Some title';
sel.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
sel.size = 1;
```

Once I have added the options and have done a
`document.getElementById('someOtherID').appendChild(sel);`
I get my select element.

What I want to do is, at A above, add:
`sel.onChange = 'someJavascriptFunction()';`
but it doesn't like it.

Should I be thinking outside of the square?  Which one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The event name should be lowercase, and you need to assign a function instead of a string.

```
sel.onchange = someJavascriptFunction;
```

If there's more work to do, you can assign an anonymous function.

```
              //  v----assign this function
sel.onchange = function() {
    // do some work
    someJavascriptFunction();  // invoke this function
};
```

Comment: I chose to go down this path and have now run into another problem in as much as the someJavascriptFunction() in the function() scope needs to be generated as a "for" loop, eg:

Comment: I chose to go down this path and have now run into another problem in as much as the someJavascriptFunction();'s in the function() scope need to be generated within a "for" loop. I can build the list of functions outside of the function() scope, but how do I get it into the scope.

Answer (score 0):

You should be doing something like this:

```
sel.onChange = someJavascriptFunction;
```

(notice that there are no parens after `someJavascriptFunction`.  This means you are attaching the function, not the invocation of the function.

Answer (score 0):

If there's a chance you'll be binding multiple functions to that event, you will want to use this slightly more lengthy method.

```
if (sel.addEventListener) {
    sel.addEventListener('change', changeFunction, false);
} else if (sel.attachEvent) {
    sel.attachEvent('onchange', changeFunction);
} else {
    sel.onchange = changeFunction;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An easier way to do the whole thing is: somewhere already in your page:

<div id=someContainer></div>

then in your javascript do this:

document.getElementById('someContainer').innerHTML = "<select id=someId title='some title' size=1 style='font-weight: bold' onchange='someJavascriptFunction()' >";

or more slowly:

var html = "<select id=someId title='some title' size=1 style='font-weight: bold' onchange='someJavascriptFunction()' >";

var someContainer = document.getElementById('someContainer');

someContainer.innerHTML = html;

The document.getElementById() is so common, you might have a library like jquery or prototype that does that more easily like $('someContainer'), or else  define it for yourself (var $ = document.getElementById;).

innerHTML is a pseudo-variable on every dom element that returns, or sets, all the html INSIDE the element you do it on.  You can pass it arbitrarily long HTML, the whole page I guess if you want.  and you can write a crafty program to build the html text, they even have templating systems like hogan (google it).